# Regular expression for numbers only

Tags: javascript

I am using the following code to detect if a string is a number:

```
 var numberPattern = /[a-zA-Z]/;

if (!numberPattern.test($(this).text())) {
    numberSort = true;
} else {
    numberSort = false;
    return numberSort;
}
```

But i have something like "(123)" and it detects it as number. Can somebody help me to update the regex to detect the paranthesys too?
I have tried: /[a-zA-Z]/(/)/ but does not work.

Comment: That update with the wrongly-escaped parenthesis wouldn't even compile, no? You don't get a syntax error? Have you considered even a minor regex tutorial or just searching the web? This is a multiple dupe.

Comment: So if your string does contain at least one letter, then you set `numberSort` equal to true--how is that supposed to make sense? In that case you also don't return `numberSort`--is that how it's supposed to be? To check if something is a number, can't you just use `!isNan(number)`? Why are you using regexp at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\d` for matching digit and [start and end anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to check entire string.

```
var numberPattern = /^\d+$/;

return numberPattern.test($(this).text());
```